# How frequently should I deploy Infrastructure as Code (IaC)

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-data-factory

I am creating release pipelines in Azure DevOps for a data integration project. I created a separate release pipeline for deploying infrastructure. This is an Infrastructure as Code(IaC) which provisions Azure resources such as SQL Server, Service bus queue namespace, KeyVault, DataFactory etc.

My second release pipeline is for  Application code such as data factory pipelines, azure functions, some .net libraries, dacpacs etc.

It made perfect sense for me to separate them as I can deploy infrastructure less frequently and application code more frequently.

Here are the questions now.

1> Is it a good practice to separate infrastructure code and application code.

2> How frequently that I should be running the IaC release pipeline?

3> Whenever I make changes to application code, is it necessary that I run both release pipelines or just releasing application code is enough?

Basically I am looking for some best practices on releasing both IaC and Application Deployment. Thanks in advance.